# How to store Facebook user education in neo4j

Tags: java, facebook, nosql, relationship, neo4j

I want to store Facebook educations of a user in Neo4j, so that i can query on any attribute combinations.

Currently Fields I want to save of Facebook education field
**https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,education&access_token=.....**

```
{
id:1
name:"xyz"
education": [   
{"school": {"id":2 "","name": "A"}, 
 "degree": {"id":3 "","name": "B"},
 "year":   {"id":4 "","name": "C"}, 
 "type": "X",
},.....]
}
```

In MySQL I will create an education table with following table
user_id, school_id,degree_id,year_id,type

Not sure whats the best way to store it in Neo4j.

 1. possible solution is 

Node User --------->(edu relationship) ---> Node school

                        degree,year,type
                     are relationship attributes.

Not sure it will be be fast if we traverse users on type and degree attributes.

Is there any other or better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Education Details returned by Facebook are not always in a strict format and some information or indeed the facebook_ids for those object could be missing. You should store the entire Education array straight in the database in a single field.

Use code to then display the data you want, accounting for missing fields etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to query every field then you should explode it as much as possible in the graph IMHO.